# Asymptotic Behaviour of the Sum of All Elements of an Inverse Symmetric Toeplitz-Matrix

Tags: matrices, limits

Let $\alpha = e^{-1/N}$ and define the KMS matrix $$G_{ij} = \alpha^{\left|i-j\right|}$$ for $i,j = 1, \dots, N+1$.
The inverse of $G$ is known and it is easily shown that the sum of all matrix elements tends to $3/2$ as $N$ tends to infinity:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} 1^T G^{-1} 1 = 3/2.$$  (Here, $1$ denotes the vector where every element is equal to one).

What happens if I add some real number $\theta > 0$ to all elements on $G$'s diagonal?
Numerical simulation shows that
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} 1^T\left(G+\theta \,\text{Id}\right)^{-1}1 = 3/2,$$
for all $\theta > 0$. ($\text{Id}$ is the identity matrix).

I would like to prove this without explicitly calculating the inverse. Can anybody help me?